# Why is -o- used to connect demographic entities?

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms, compounds, morphology, greek

Consider Indo-China, Indo-US, Indo-European, Afro-American, Sino-American.
Why is O used to connect the two areas ?

Comment: This is an interesting question. There is one more, "Franco-German".

Comment: Well! I dont see an "O" in "Asia-Pacific", "Af-Pak" !!

Comment: @Monzoor , Well, I did not say that O is used in all cases !

Comment: I humbly agree. This was just an interesting observation.

Comment: Also: *Serbo-Croatian* and probably many others.

Comment: The three prefixes *afro*, *serbo* and *sino* all come from Latin  so maybe that has something to do with it. See, for example, http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Sino-

Comment: @Clare , Interesting Point !

Comment: @Rathony Plus an awful lot of Anglo-Somethings.

Comment: @WS2 That's what I included in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An -o- is commonly used as a connecting vowel in Greek compound words. Since Greek has been an influential source of terms in many European languages, from Latin to English, this connecting -o- also shows up in a fair number of English words.

I don't know the details of why or in what circumstances connecting -o- was used in Greek. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/-o-) says it originated from the thematic vowel of nouns and adjectives.

Comment: M-W's "used as a connective vowel originally to join word elements of Greek origin and now also to join word elements of Latin or other origin <speedometer> <elastomer>" was  helpful to me.

Comment: +1 , "Definition of -o-" in MW must be the closest we can get , to answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

According to Online Etymology Dictionary, [Indo-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=indo) is from Greek:

> word-forming element meaning "of or pertaining to India" (and some other place), from Greek Indo-, from Indos "India"

[Sino-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=sino) is from Latin, Greek and Arabic:

before vowels Sin-, word-forming element meaning "Chinese," 1879, from Late Latin Sinæ (plural) "the Chinese," from Ptolemaic Greek Sinai, from Arabic Sin "China," probably from Chinese Ch'in, name of the fourth dynasty of China

"[Anglo-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=anglo)" , "[Franco-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=franco)" and "[Afro-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=afro) all are from Latin.

It is common to make a compound noun using those adjectives that end with "o" when you need to make new words such as Anglophone, Francophone, Anglophilia, Francophilia, xenophobia, xenophilia, afrophile, indophile, etc.

"O" is broadly used in adjectives of many European languages which has a Prot**o**-Ind**o**-European root. Using those words are more idiomatic than using Indian, African, Chinese, French, etc. You can find "[Germano-French relations](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s45BVoWaOIrN8gf1lpygCA#q=%22Germano-French+relations%22)", but I doubt it sounds more idiomatic than "[German-French relations](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s45BVoWaOIrN8gf1lpygCA#q=%22German-French+relations%22)".

Comment: The same thing applies in French - *l'hôpital Franco-Brittanique*.